# searching a matching value in tcl

Tags: tcl

I have below lists

```
set a [list aa ab abc1 120 2ab 00]
set b [list aa bb dd]
set c [list ab bc cd]
set d [list abc0 abc1 abc2]
set e [list 110 040 120]
set f [list 1ab 2ab 3ab 4ab]
set g [list 00 11 22]
```

From list "b" to list "g" I want to search with list "a" and also if any match found then I want that value.

-inline will give the exact match but for single element. for multiple values I have written below code but it is not giving me output on terminal.

consider an example to find a matching value between list "a" and list "b"

```
foreach content $b {
set matching_value [lsearch -inline $a $content]
}
```

and also if match found, that value should return and I don't want to compare with next values within same list if any.

`puts $matching_value` doesn't giving me any output, how should I break once match found ?

Comment: The variable `a` has 6 elements in it. Do you want to search for each element of this list in the list `b` ?

Comment: Variable a has matching element aa in list b. Only that element I need to search and return that element to be assigned with other variable say  "matching_value".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way might be to fetch the index, and do a `lindex` and `break` if the value is present:

```
foreach content $b {
    set idx [lsearch $a $content]
    if {$idx >= 0} {
        set matching_value [lindex $a $idx]
        break
    }
}
```

We use the index because then we can *definitely* determine if the search failed; we don't have that guarantee *in general* when using `lsearch -inline` since theoretically any value could be present in the list.

Comment: Thanks a lot :).. resolved after a simple edit if {$idx == 0}

Comment: @Krishh: use >= instead to find items that aren't in first position.